# How to hide native admob ad from javascript?

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I've developed an android phonegap application. The app make use of native admob ad code where the ad is displayed at the bottom of the app. I chose the native method instead of javascript intergration because the native version allow me to have more option to modify in admob website. My question: Is it possible to hide/unhide admob ad from javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a plugin which will show/hide the ad banner. 
Here is an example:

com.example.AdBanner:

```
public class AdBannerPlugin extends Plugin {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION_SHOW_AD_BANNER = "com.example.SHOW_AD_BANNER";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION_HIDE_AD_BANNER = "com.example.HIDE_AD_BANNER";
    private static final String ACTION_SHOW_AD_BANNER = "showBanner";
    private static final String ACTION_HIDE_AD_BANNER = "hideBanner";

    /**
     * @see Plugin#execute(String, org.json.JSONArray, String)
     */
    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(final String action, final JSONArray data, final String callbackId) {
        if (ACTION_SHOW_AD_BANNER.equals(action)) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION_SHOW_AD_BANNER);
            this.ctx.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
            return new PluginResult(OK);
        } else if (ACTION_HIDE_AD_BANNER.equals(action)) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION_HIDE_AD_BANNER);
            this.ctx.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
            return new PluginResult(OK);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unsupported action: " + action);
            return new PluginResult(INVALID_ACTION);
        }
    }
}
```

In your main activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver adReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (BROADCAST_ACTION_SHOW_AD_BANNER.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //check if the ad view is not visible and show it 
        } else if (BROADCAST_ACTION_HIDE_AD_BANNER.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //check if the ad view is visible and hide it
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION_HIDE_AD_BANNER);
    intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION_SHOW_AD_BANNER);
    registerReceiver(adReceiver, intentFilter);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(adReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

In plugins.xml:

```
<plugin name="com.example.AdBanner" value="com.example.AdBannerPlugin"/>
```

Now you can hide ad banner from javascript:

```
cordova.exec(onSuccess, onFail, 'com.example.AdBanner', 'hideBanner', []);
```